# How did "spina" shift semantically from "thorn" or "prickle" to "backbone"?

Tags: etymology

From the online etymology dictionary (boldface mine):

> [spine (n.)](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spine)
>   c. 1400, "backbone," later "thornlike part" (early 15c.),
>   from Old French *espine* "thorn, prickle; backbone, spine" (12c., Modern French *épine*),
>   from Latin *spina* "**backbone**," originally "**thorn, prickle**" (figuratively, in plural, "difficulties, perplexities"),
>   from PIE **spe-ina-*, from root **spei-*  "sharp point" (see [*spike*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=spike&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)).
>   Meaning "the back of a book" is first attested 1922.

I do not comprehend the underlying semantic notions for the entitled question; the human spine does not resemble or feel like a “thorn, prickle”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me the "[processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28anatomy%29)"

[image: vertebra]

look like thorns

[image: spine]

Comment: But it's not the vertebrae that are called *spinae*, only the spine. There's nothing about vertebrae in Lewis & Short (nor in English): http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=spina&filter=CUTF8

Comment: @Cerberus "not the vertebrae [...] only the spine": What do you mean? The vertebrae _are_ the spine. (E.g. from oxforddictionaries.com "spine: a series of vertebrae [...]") I was thinking that if _spina_ meant "thorn" initially, it could have come to mean "spine", because the spine is a long thorny thing. (The "thorns" are called processes now—from Latin _processus_, of course, but in the sense of "outgrowth of tissue from a larger body" this word is bound to have a shorter etymology, at least shorter than something as simple as "spine/backbone".)

Comment: Very well: a vertebra is not a spine, and a vertebra is never called a *spina*, only the spine is. A vertebra may contain processes, but containing x is not the same as being x. A spina may have a thorny shape and thus be called a thorn, but not because it contains thorns, or it'd be a pars pro toto. But the dictionaries do not mention any pars pro toto, they just say a spine is called a *spina*, the most obvious conexion (x=y because x resembles y, not p=q because p contains things that resemble q).

Comment: @Cerberus OK, I agree with you and as you can tell from my 7-word answer, I didn't intend it to be more than a guess.

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with guesses! I was just expressing a bit of scepsis.

Answer (score 10):

[Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=spina&filter=CUTF8) say it came to refer to various things shaped like a thorn or prickle in its transferred senses, under which they group "backbone". Our backbone is a long, thin object, after all. Perhaps their sense number 2 elucidates the etymological path for you: a **fish-bone**. Those are pointed and can prick into your flesh, and they resemble backbones in that they are bones.